# Behavior Space Reporters once per time period

Tags: netlogo

I want to record data while running Behavior Space once within a given period, e.g. once per 1000 ticks. I see that Behavior Space can call reporters once per tick or once at the end of the simulation run. However, I do not want to record once per tick, because that produces too much data, but I also don't want to just have data at the end of the simulation. I cannot change the simulation time represented by `tick` because of numerical stability. I tried putting code into Behavior space, i.e.
    if ticks mod 1000 = 0 [reporter]

but this gave an error ("Syntax, expected reporter") when I started the experiment. Is there a way around this issue, or am I stuck with gathering too much or too little data? Thx.

Comment: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#everynticks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "Go commands", put `repeat 1000 [ go ]` instead of just `go`. That way, each "step" is actually 1000 ticks, so recording the data each step records it once every 1000 ticks.

Comment: Works great! Thank you